# Cart Price Rules - Quantity in cart equals or greater than 10 (from a same category, but with different sku's)

Tags: cart, price, quantity, rules

We face an issue here. We want to create a 5%, 10%, and 15% rebate when customer add 5, 10, or 15 units of a same category.

It work well, until magento dont advise that the condition "Quantity in cart equals or greater than 10" need to be for the same sku depiste we add the condition "from category x".

if I add 2 units of X, and 3 units of Y from the same category, we are supposed to trigger the 5% discount rule, but because it is not the same sku, it dont work. I hit a wall here as we work one full day on these rules.

[image]